# What are the actual speeds of the burn speed options in Zune Software?

Tags: windows-media-player, zune-software

In the Zune Software (and in Windows Media Player) you can choose between four burn speeds: fastest, fast, medium, and slow. What speeds (e.g. 1x, 4x, 16x) do those settings correspond to?

Comment: They might not correspond to anything.  I am sure there is a reason they didn't use ( 1x, 2x, 4x, 6x, ... ) and instead used the actual words to describe speeds options.

Comment: I figured they were just trying to simplify it. I'm trying to burn a disc at 1x, and am somewhat disbelievingly discovering that all the software I have with burning capability doesn't actually say what speed it can burn at.